# Maven throws "Cannot find symbol" in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I'm creating a local instance for Jenkins and Sonarqube.
After creating project and after configuring the same, I clicked "Build Now".
In the console output I can see that Maven starts to download the required meta data and once that is completed it throws **Compilation error** "**Cannot find symbol**" for each of the file in the project.

Maven is also installed installed in my machine and, I tried downloading the project from GIT and ran maven via command prompt it builds successfully. Only if I build via Jenkins I'm getting this issue. Can someone please help me out with this.

Sonar Error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project XXXXXXX: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/api/utils/SonarException : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm = plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories /1/org/codehaus/mojo/sonar-maven-plugin/2.6/sonar-maven-plugin-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.1/maven-dependency-tree-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.11/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.5/plexus-utils-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/org/codehaus/sonar/runner/sonar-runner-api/2.4/sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/com/google/guava/guava/10.0.1/guava-10.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.3/jsr305-2.0.3.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import from realm ClassRealm[project>com.XXXX.etl:XXXX:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]

[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Which symbol is it referring to ? is it more then a single symbol ?

Comment: You have to be more specific on the error you are saying. `Cannot find symbol` occurs when something on the classpath is wrong so maven cannot find any classes therefore their methods which cause this error. See if you have maven properly installed. See if you java a jdk installed on the jenkins server instead of a jre. see if you have the proper enviroment variables set. see if your project does not use any local library (one that you have only on your machine).

Comment: Jorge Campos you are right.
I have deleted the maven instance. Downloaded and installed a fresh copy did the trick for me.

Comment: But now getting this in sonar "failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli)"

Comment: Once again, those are a very general exceptions - you should provide the whole error as there many reasons for the plugin to fail.

Comment: @ShmulikKlein I have updated the post with the error log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please specify the compilation version of Java. This is the reason why You are facing this issue - UnsupportedClassVersionError
try adding something like this in Your pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- START Of Plugins -->
        <!-- MAVEN COMPILER PLUGIN -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- END Of Plugins -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here I have used 1.7 jdk. But You can change that if required.

Please let know if it works...

Comment: That's it I was using JDK 1.6 upgrading to 1.7 did the trick.
Other than that I found another solution too. 
If Jenkins, maven and Sonar are installed in the same system you can mention "sonar:sonar" under build it works in with jdk1.6 itself. Report can be viewed in sonar.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. The problem was that Jenkins service was running on JRE, even though JDK was configured in the system properly. To solve it, I had to stop Jenkins service, delete JRE, modify Jenkins XML to point to JDK, and then restart Jenkins service. Only then it worked.